# How do I sum all the values that returning from the multiplying of two columns?

Tags: excel, worksheet-function

B5*C5+B6*C6... till 30, but in a formula...

**Example:**

```
B - C
3 - 40
4 - 50
1 - 60
0 - 20
3 - 80
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow Nighthawk - but this question should really be on SuperUser!

Comment: It's another site within the StackExchange network - http://superuser.com/ - and is more for advanced software solutions rather than programming/scripting questions. When people mark questions as `close`, they can recommend an alternative site. If enough people mark it, the question will be moved automatically.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Does a formula like this meet your requirement?

```
=SUMPRODUCT(B5:B30,C5:C30)
```

Comment: I have a last question..

How can i do the same as you told me, but just if on D column i have the word "No"
so if:
B C D
2 30 No
1 60 YES
1 50 No

it will just give me the result of 2*30 and 1*50 ?

Comment: Enter as an array formula `=SUM(B5:B30*C5:C30*(D5:D30="No"))`

Comment: As some alternatives to Chris' solution, you could: a) enter `=SUMPRODUCT(B5:B30,C5:C30,IF(D5:D30="No",1,0))` as an array formula, or, b) create formulas in column E that convert "No" into 1 starting with `=IF(D5="No",1,0)` in cell E5, and then use a "regular" (non-array) form of SUMPRODUCT as `=SUMPRODUCT(B5:B30,C5:C30,E5:E30)`

Answer (score 1):

Make D5 be `=B5*C5`, and the same for D6, D7, etc... then your formula would simply be `=SUM(D5:D10)`

Comment: Thanks for the answer.. But
That is the solution i already did, i want a solution without using Intermediator..